# Increasing splitsize vs dfs block size

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Difference between splits and blocks is a block is the physical data stored on the HDFS whereas splits are the one that are calculated/generated by InputFormat's like - TextInputFormat, FileInputFormat etc.

I read in many places that it is suggestible to increase *split-size* rather than *block size* if we want to reduce the number of map tasks. But, can any one tell me why it is so?

Also, what would be the consequences of altering split-size vs dfs block-size in different scenarios as below? (*Assume initially split-size and block size is 64MB*)

1. Increase split-size and keep dfs-block size same

   - This would decrease number of map taks.
2. Split-size unaltered but dfs-block size increased

   - In this case number of map tasks doesn't change as the split size remains same (Is my understanding correct?)
3. Both split size and dfs-block size increased

   - This would decrease number of map-tasks.

Is my above understanding in different scenarios correct? If so, can any one tell me what's the difference/consequences between ***scenario 1*** and ***scenario 3***.

Comment: Go through below link. https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-user/201211.mbox/%3CCAOcnVr14NuOCDAw1=5wLooWHc5kQMO7o4z9TKrZKv=uA1LqQrw@mail.gmail.com%3E http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-user/201211.mbox/%3CCAOcnVr05Eiboox7SKaoRZ_=jNpdB7ym3MFtWpVYXdd1waXqAEg@mail.gmail.com%3E Hope this could help you.